# jQuery buttons onclick in jQuery button not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this program where you can create draggable `<div></div>'s`, the div can then be dragged to a `<td></td>` in a table and when you hover over the `<td></td>` **a** **button** is displayed.

But, I'm having trouble with the button that's displayed when the user hovers over the `<td></td>'s`
there is**1 thing** that is confusing me:

1. The onclick function in the button isn't working. I tried doing something like this, but it didn't work:

   ```
       `<button onclick="myfunction()">Click</button>`
   ```

If you could help me, I would really appreciate it.

**In more detail here is what my code aims to do:**

user inputs text -> users input is outputted in a draggable div -> user can drag output into a `<td></td>` -> user can then click a button (which is displayed on hover) to delete the content in the `<td></td>`

**Here is the full version of my code:**

```js
function addElement () { 
  
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  
  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id = 'temp'

  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text); 
  
  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 

  $(function() {
    
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    $(div).draggable();
    $("#temp").draggable();

    $(td).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) { 
          $( this )
          .addClass("div")
            .html( text );
              $("div").draggable();

          $( "#temp" ).remove();
      }
    });
  });


  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";



$(function () {
    $("td").dblclick(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var currentEle = $(this);
        var value = $(this).html();
        updateVal(currentEle, value);
    });
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + text + '" />');
    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function () {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
    });
}

}



    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

  $( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<button>Click</button>" ) );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).find( "button" ).last().remove();
  }
);
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 20px ;
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 20px ;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}


.div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

td{
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px ;
  width: 200px;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Input text:</h1>
    <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="input">
    <button onclick="addElement()" >input</button> 

    <p>Drag your outputs to the div:</p>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td height="50" width=100></td>
  </tr>
</table>


     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.So the problem is, you include this `hover` in function `addElement()`, which will run every time you click `input`:

```
$( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<button>Click</button>" ) );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).find( "button" ).last().remove();
  }
);
```

How to fix: just put it outside of `addElement()` function.

2. Make sure to have `myfunction()` declared globally, at the same level as `addElement()`

You could try this here: https://jsfiddle.net/Kienht/kh59nx23/2/

However, this just helps answer your 2 questions above, doesn't mean that there is no more issues. `id` must be unique. You attach the `id` `#temp` to all of the new `div` you create, which will cause you problem later on when user input multiple times. Please consider this.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to delete the "data" in the td, when the user clicks the button i'm trying to make everything in the td disappear with this(but it doesn't work) how can I call the current td the user is hovering or the most recent one the user hovered? :                               
 `function dump() {
     var hover = $("td").hover;
      $( hover ).remove();
    }
$( "button" ).on( "click", dump );`

Comment: `this` inside the function `hover` will point to the current element that the user is hovering on. You can try to `console.log(this)` to see